# PHP empty var == 0?

Tags: php, variables, evaluation

In php 5

```
  $my_var = "";

  if ($my_var == 0) {
    echo "my_var equals 0";

  }
```

Why it evaluates true? Is there some reference in php.net about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PHP is a weakly typed language](http://au.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). Empty strings and boolean false will evaluate to 0 when tested with the equal operator `==`. On the other hand, you can force it to check the type by using the identical operator `===` as such:

```
$my_var = "";

if ($my_var === 0) {
   echo "my_var equals 0";
} else {
   echo "my_var does not equal 0";
}
```

This should give you a ton of information on the subject: [How do the PHP equality (== double equals) and identity (=== triple equals) comparison operators differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comparis)

Answer (score 3):

A string and an integer are not directly comparable with `==`. So PHP performs type juggling to see if there is another sensible comparison available.

When a string is compared with an integer, the string first gets converted to an integer. You can find the details of the conversion [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion). Basically, since `""` is not a valid number, the result of the conversion is `0`. Thus, the comparison becomes `0 == 0` which is clearly true.

You'll probably want to use the identity comparison `===` for most (if not all) your comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

In your first line, you define `$my_var` as string.

Inside the comparison you compare that variable with a constant integer.

If you want exact comparison (I don't know why you need to compare a string with an integer without any cast), you should use the `===`:

```
if ($my_var === 0) {
  echo "my_var equals 0";
}
```

That will never echo the message.

The PHP manual defines in [Comparison Operators section](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), the operator `==` as:

> TRUE if $a is equal to $b after type juggling.

So, the important thing here is [`type juggling`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

As a matter of fact, in [PHP Manual: types comparisons](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php), the second table tell you exactly that integer `0` equals string `""`.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the type coercion that comes from the equality operator you are using.

The [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) has the Type Comparison tables to shed a light on this.

Its generally considered a good practice to utilize the identical operator `===` instead, as to avoid such corner(?) cases.

Answer (score 0):

here is the reference in the php manual about boolean values

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

and here is the reference for the NULL value

```
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php

$my_var = '';

if ($my_var == 0) {
    echo "my_var equals 0"
}
```

evaluates to true because "" is the same as NULL which evaluates to false or 0